# What's the meaning of these ip route rules

Tags: route, iproute

There are some IP route rules in an old code, but I don't know the meaning of them:

```bsh
ip route flush table 100
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

Comment: Hello DerekChen. You've seen `man ip` - did you notice that the subcommands are detailed at the end of the document under the `SEE ALSO` section? Specifically,`man ip-route` and `man ip-rule`

Comment: Are you looking at `ss-rules` from luci-app-shadowsocks?

Answer (score 4):

One line at time:

```bsh
ip route flush table 100
```

should clear table with ID 100.

```bsh
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
```

adds a rule to packets marked as `1` (I suppose with a `--set-mark 1` in iptables) to be referenced with table 100.
More on [`ip rule` documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-rule.8.html).

```bsh
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

routes all the traffic (`0.0.0.0/0` is equivalent to `default`) to the device `lo`, i.e. the *local loopback*, a therm in which the local system is called.

It is not mandatory to the table ID to be an integer (100 in your example), it could be a string too. [Here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html) an interesting example.

Answer (score 1):

This code is most certainly part of the setup on Linux for transparent proxy (using iptables' [`socket` match](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#socket) and [`TPROXY` target](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#TPROXY) or nftables's [`socket` expression](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/nftables/nft.8#SOCKET_EXPRESSION) and [`tproxy`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/nftables/nft.8#TPROXY_STATEMENT) statement).

from Linux kernel's documentation [`tproxy.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt):

> ```
> 1. Making non-local sockets work
> ================================
>
> The idea is that you identify packets with destination address matching a local
> socket on your box, set the packet mark to a certain value:
>
> # iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
> # iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
> # iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
> # iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
>
> Alternatively you can do this in nft with the following commands:
>
> # nft add table filter
> # nft add chain filter divert "{ type filter hook prerouting priority -150; }"
> # nft add rule filter divert meta l4proto tcp socket transparent 1 meta mark set 1 accept
>
> And then match on that value using policy routing to have those packets
> delivered locally:
>
> # ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
> # ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
> ```

the first command selects an alternate routing table for marked packets. The second command adds content to this routing table: intercept packets (that should have been routed but were diverted) to end on the local system.

This first part, above, is to keep state: connections that were diverted (by the part below) will keep being diverted, because the destination address, which isn't a native host address, will nevertheless exist on a local socket, enabled by the socket option IP_TRANSPARENT:

> ```
> Note that for this to work you'll have to modify the proxy to enable (SOL_IP,
> IP_TRANSPARENT) for the listening socket.
> ```

There has to be a dedicated application handling this. For example *squid* or *haproxy* with adequate configuration matching the following tproxy rules:

> ```
> The 'TPROXY' target provides similar functionality without relying on NAT. Simply
> add rules like this to the iptables ruleset above:
>
> # iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY \
>   --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 50080
>
> Or the following rule to nft:
>
> # nft add rule filter divert tcp dport 80 tproxy to :50080 meta mark set 1 accept
> ```